# I wrote a function in C language that as I would think has O(n^3) time complexity, but as n grows, for some reason it behaves like O(n^2)

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, array-algorithms

I have written a function that makes an array unique, but I don't quite understand how the time complexity works here.

Here's my whole program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 64000 

void fill(size_t const, int*);
void make_unique(size_t*, int**);
bool pop_back(size_t*, int**);
bool pop_front(size_t*, int**);
bool remove_at(size_t, size_t*, int**);


int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    size_t size=SIZE;
    int* arr=malloc(sizeof(int[size]));
    fill(size, arr);
    //print(size, arr);

    double time_spent = 0.0;
    clock_t begin = clock();
    make_unique(&size, &arr);
    clock_t end = clock();
    time_spent += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("\nThe elapsed time is %f seconds", time_spent);
    printf("\nArray with no equal elements: \n");
    print(size, arr);
    free(arr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void make_unique(size_t* size, int** arr){
    for(size_t i=0; i<*size; ++i)
        for(size_t j=0; j<*size;){
            if(i==j) {
                ++j;
                continue;
            }
            if((*arr)[i]==(*arr)[j]){
                remove_at(j, size, arr);
                continue;
            }
            ++j;
        }
}

bool pop_back(size_t* size, int** arr){
    if(!*arr||!*size) return false;
    int* new_arr=malloc(sizeof(int[*size-1]));
    --*size;
    for(size_t i=0; i<*size; ++i)
        new_arr[i]=(*arr)[i];
    free(*arr);
    *arr=new_arr;
    return true;
}

bool pop_front(size_t* size, int** arr){
    if(!*arr||!*size) return false;
    int* new_arr=malloc(sizeof(int[*size-1]));
    --*size;
    for(size_t i=0, j=1; i<*size; ++i, ++j)
        new_arr[i]=(*arr)[j];
    free(*arr);
    *arr=new_arr;
    return true;
}

bool remove_at(size_t pos, size_t* size, int** arr){
    if(pos==0) return pop_front(size, arr);
    if(pos==*size-1) return pop_back(size, arr);
    if(!*arr||!*size||pos>=*size) return false;

    int* new_arr=malloc(sizeof(int[*size-1]));
    for(size_t i=0; i<pos; ++i)
        new_arr[i]=(*arr)[i];
    for(size_t i=pos, j=pos+1; j<*size; ++i, ++j)
        new_arr[i]=(*arr)[j];
    --*size;
    free(*arr);
    *arr=new_arr;
    return true;
}

void fill(size_t const size, int arr*){
    for(size_t i=0; i<size; ++i){
        arr[i]=rand()%100;
    }
}
```

The algorithm itself has quadratic time, but it also uses function remove_at. Is the overall complexity cubic?

The results I got were:

```
(SIZE    - seconds)
1024 000 - 1076.92
 512 000 -  262.92
 256 000 -   65.90
 128 000 -   16.3
  64 000 -    4.11
```

It looks like my program has O(n^2) time complexity. Does it?

I compiled my code with clang compiler and ran it in terminal.

By the way, if I have some serious inaccuracies in my code, I would like to read some comments. Or an advice on how to improve the effectiveness of it.

UPD:

My last understanding of general case complexity of my program is: We have (n-d) iterations in outer loop, n/(n-d) iterations in mid loop, and (n+(n-1)+...+(n-d))/d ~ (n-d/2) iterations in inner loop. So the complexity is O((n-d)*(n/(n-d))*(n+(n-1)+...+(n-d))/d ) = O(n*(n-d/2)) = O(n^2) (d is number of duplicates). It finally seems right to me (if it's not let me know). Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: Given that `remove_at` removes an element... how many times could it possibly be called?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. A description of your algorithm (and links if applicable) might help us to analyze your code. Why do you allocate new memory in some of the functions instead of working in the same array? How did you test different sizes? By modifying the definition of `SIZE`, recompiling and running once? It might be better to replace `SIZE` with a variable you can modify at run-time, call your functions multiple times with the same size and calculate averages, maybe ignoring the first run to remove cache effects.

Comment: I generated quite big arrays up to 2M elements, and I filled it with numbers from 1 to 100. So it calls remove quite often, no?

Comment: Have you checked this code for correctness?  I suspect there's a big bug.

Comment: Since you only have 100 distinct elements, the outermost loop will only loop (at most) 100 times, no matter how large the array was originally, since the inner loop will remove all the duplicates.  So it ends up being O(n^2)

Comment: Suggestion (for performance): when doing `remove_at()` rather than moving all relevant array elements 1 position backwards, take the very last *active* element and copy it to the place you want to remove. You'll change the order of the initial elements, but they're random to begin with. Anyway (move all elements backwards or copy the last one), **you don't need to copy (and `malloc()` and `free()`) the array**!!

Comment: OK, thank you, Mr Dodd, for your answer. Now I understand it

Comment: pmg, thank you for your suggestion! Can't believe I didn't this idea on my own. Rewrote it with new remove_at function.
"But I have one more question. You said, 'Anyway, (move all elements backwards or copy the last one), you don't need to copy (and use malloc() and free()) the array!' - How can I move all elements without using malloc, free, etc.? Do you mean I should work with the same array but, in each i-th iteration, operate with size-i elements of the array?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has O(n^2) worst case time complexity, even though it looks like it's O(n^3).

For every element that's a duplicate of an earlier element, you incur O(n) work to remove it. There's at most n-1 of these elements, so the total cost of this duplicate removal is O(n^2).

So you spend O(n^2) time finding the duplicates, and O(n^2) time removing the duplicates. That the "remove duplicate" code appears inside the nested loops is irrelevant because it's not called for most loop iterations.

Comment: Excuse me, but your answer doesn't seem correct to me. The thing is, as Chris Dodd said in the comments, that the outermost loop will only loop 100 times. Also, the remove_at function has O(n) time complexity, and it's called pretty much for every element since we only have 100 unique values out of thousands of millions I fiil the array with.

Comment: Your code always runs in quadratic time no matter what the array of initialized with. My answer ignores the fact you're initializing with only 100 different values because it's not relevant for the complexity.

Comment: Something that's O(n) and is called for pretty much every element contributes O(n^2) to the complexity. I say this in my answer...

Comment: @krotovukha: No matter how many times the loops in `make_unique` execute, `remove_at` is only called at most d times, where d is the total number od duplicate elements. d is always less than n, regardless of how you fill the array. The d calls to `remove_at` do n work each, a total of dn. In all the iterations in `make_unique`, d of them do n work (dn total), and all the rest of them (O(n^2) of them) do O(1) work—just comparing two elements and not calling `remove_at`. So the total is dn+n^2, not dn^2.

Comment: Eric Postpischil, You are almost right. I think you are confusing the values of d and n-d a little bit.  Indeed, remove_at is called d times, but in my examples d is very large and comparable to n. d calls to remove_at do n/2 work at average (n in the first iteration and 100 in the last one). So we get total of dn/2 ~ (n^2)/2. The outermost loop is the one that is running very few times, so we don't consider it. The overall complexity is O((n^2)/2)=O(n^2). Correct me if I'm wrong again

Comment: Paul Hankin, Sorry, I think i misunderstood your answer. What confuses me is the "So you spend O(n^2) time finding the duplicates, and O(n^2) time removing the duplicates" part. 
I spend O(n) time finding the duplicates, and O(n) time removing each of them, so we get O(n^2) in total. 
And also, I don't understand the "That the "remove duplicate" code appears inside the nested loops is irrelevant because it's not called for most loop iterations." part. It's relevant cause it's called ~n times and each n call does n/2 (in average) work inside the remove_at function

Comment: Eric Postpischil, OK, I got that you explained it in more general case, where d is not necessarily comparable to n. So in general case the mid loop will always do n iteration, and the sum of outermost and innermost loops iterations wiil also be n, right?

Comment: @krotovukha yes, I'm using O(n^2) in its exact meaning -- an upper bound. You can read my explanation as "you spend at most O(n^2) time finding duplicates and at most O(n^2) time removing duplicates, so the overall time is O(n^2)." You can break the numbers down more carefully by accounting for the number of duplicates and how that affects the number of iterations of the outer loop to get the same answer in a more complicated way. That's what you started with the idea that the outer loop executes at most d times if there's at most d unique elements in the array, and what Eric is detailing.

Comment: Paul Hakin, Eric Postpischil
I wrote bunch of stupid things in the comments and I feel sorry about it. My last understanding of general case complexity of my program is:
We have (n-d) iterations in outer loop, n/(n-d) iterations in mid loop, and (n+(n-1)+...+(n-d))/d ~ (n-d/2) iterations in inner loop. So the complexity is O((n-d)*(n/(n-d))*(n+(n-1)+...+(n-d))/d ) = O(n*(n-d/2)) = O(n^2) (d is number of duplicates). It finally seems right to me.
Thank you all for helping me